# FILE type throwing error: invalid use of non-static member function

Tags: c++, file

I am trying to read in a binary file into a structure starting at the a specific member of the structure. However, when I try to do this, I get the following error:

`error: invalid use of non-static member function`

I am wondering why this is happening?

```
typedef struct  eh {    /* ethernet header          */
    unsigned char eh_dst[6];
    unsigned char eh_src[6];
    unsigned short eh_type;
} ethHead;

typedef struct  ep  {        /* complete structure of Ethernet packet*/
    short   ep_ifn;      /* originating interface number        */
    short   ep_len;      /* length of the packet            */
    struct eh ep_eh;     /* the ethernet header         */
    char ep_data[1500];
    unsigned long ep_crc;
} ethFrame;

ep epReadFromFile(string nameOfFile){
    FILE *fp = fopen(nameOfFile.c_str, "rb");
    ep EPH;

    if (fp != 0) {
        fread(&EPH.ep_eh, sizeof(ep), 1, fp);
        printf("reading in File");
    }
    else {
        printf("Can't read file");
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return EPH;
}
```

Additionally, if there is a better way of doing this with fstream, I would greatly appreciate the suggestion.

I have tried standard library to do this using:

```
ep epReadFromFile(string nameOfFile){
    ifstream input_file(nameOfFile, ios::binary);
    ep ethernetPacket;
    input_file.read((char*)&ethernetPacket.ep_eh, sizeof(eh));
    return ethernetPacket;
}
```

but this does not properly read in the file.

Comment: C++ and C are different languages.  Tags edited.

Comment: All other considerations notwithstanding, you are attempting to read data as large as a whole `struct ep`, but you are trying to store it in space smaller than a whole `struct ep`.  That cannot possibly work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using `nameOfFile.c_str`, which is a member function of the string class.

change it to `nameOfFile.c_str()`